# Assign "glyphicon download-alt" icon to a submit button

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with adding glyphicon icon to a submit button. Once I try it with "a" tag, the action did not work when I press the button. So how do I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<%=Const.ActionURIs.INSTRUCTOR_COURSE_STUDENT_LIST_DOWNLOAD%>" style="display:inline;">
            <input id="button_download" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                    name="<%=Const.ParamsNames.FEEDBACK_RESULTS_UPLOADDOWNLOADBUTTON%>"
                    value=" Download Student List ">

            <input type="hidden" name="<%=Const.ParamsNames.USER_ID%>" value="${data.account.googleId}">
            <input type="hidden" name="<%=Const.ParamsNames.COURSE_ID%>" value="${courseDetails.course.id}">
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<button>` tag instead of an `<input>` tag. Change your button like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button_download" name="<%=Const.ParamsNames.FEEDBACK_RESULTS_UPLOADDOWNLOADBUTTON%>">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Download Student List
</button>
```

The reason it doesn't work is given on [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use).

*Don't mix with other components* : Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested `<span>` and apply the icon classes to the `<span>`.

**Working example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Download Student List
</button>
</form>
```